# 2015 hawk 250cc enduro motorcycle

Tags: motorcycle, ignition

While riding down the street, our motorcycle just died. Tried to restart it and it sounded like it wasn't firing. We changed the plug and ignition coil and still not firing. What should we do now?

Comment: Does the engine turn over? did you accidentally hit the engine stop button on the throttle side controls?

Comment: It turns over just not firing. And no he didn't hit the engine stop button.

Comment: @ChristieSchutes - Did your issue get resolved or are you still having it?

Answer (score 2):

Unscrew the spark plug, and touch the edge of the plug where the thread is to the metal engine block somewhere near where the plug is threaded into the engine. Make sure you don't have gas fumes everywhere. Hold on to the plug via the insulated wire, so you don't get shocked. Make sure to keep the plug threads touching the engine, and the center electrode from touching anything.

Turn the engine over.

## It sparks.

If you have spark there are two potential options I have come across.

1. (less likely) Your timing is totally screwed up. This is unlikely and I have only seen it on higher strung 250cc mx engines that may have snapped the key off the timing wheel and spun on the crank. This can cause it to run terribly or not at all.
2. (most likely) Your fueling is not functioning. From what I gather your motorcycle has a carburetor. When you turn the bike over a bunch and pull the plug out, is it wet with fuel? If not, you need to walk through the fuel system and determine if there are any blockages. Most of the time the carb's float has gotten stuck and will no longer allow fuel into the bowl. This will prevent any gas from getting into your new bike's engine, preventing it from turning over.

## It doesn't spark.

If you do not have spark, it could very well be the kickstand shutoff switch. This mysterious and frustrating malady has struck myself and friends many times. On nearly any new moto sold there is a small switch that detects if the kickstand is up or down.

If it *thinks* the kickstand is down, you will get zero spark. If it's actually down is a whole different issue. I have seen these switches fail on just about every kind of motorcycle. Many people cut the switch off and hardwire it to always be "up" so they don't get stranded in the woods / desert. I don't just because I'm forgetful and it has saved me at least once.